# How can I make the last item of the woocommerce breadcrumb clickable?

Tags: wordpress, hook, hook-woocommerce, breadcrumbs

For some reasons, I need the last item of the breadcrumb be **linked to the current page**. I saw some examples for:
*woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults, woocommerce_breadcrumb_home_url, woocommerce_breadcrumb_main_term, woocommerce_breadcrumb_product_terms_args*,
but non of them helped.
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to override the `breadcrumb.php` template from the plugin to your theme. follow the below steps.

Copy `breadcrumb.php` file from

```
wp-content/pluings/woocommerce/templates/global/breadcrumb.php
```

and upload to this path.

```
wp-content/themes/your-active-theme-name/woocommerce/global/breadcrumb.php
```

Now you will see the code in `breadcrumb.php` like this

```
<?php
/**
 * Shop breadcrumb
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/global/breadcrumb.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files, and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package     WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version     2.3.0
 * @see         woocommerce_breadcrumb()
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! empty( $breadcrumb ) ) {

    echo $wrap_before;

    foreach ( $breadcrumb as $key => $crumb ) {

        echo $before;

        if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . esc_html( $crumb[0] ) . '</a>';
        } else {
            echo esc_html( $crumb[0] );
        }

        echo $after;

        if ( sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
            echo $delimiter;
        }
    }

    echo $wrap_after;

}
```

**Change this line**

```
if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
```

**With this**

```
if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key ) {
```

**Complete code will look like this**

```
<?php
/**
 * Shop breadcrumb
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/global/breadcrumb.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files, and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package     WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version     2.3.0
 * @see         woocommerce_breadcrumb()
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! empty( $breadcrumb ) ) {

    echo $wrap_before;

    foreach ( $breadcrumb as $key => $crumb ) {

        echo $before;

        if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key ) {
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . esc_html( $crumb[0] ) . '</a>';
        } else {
            echo esc_html( $crumb[0] );
        }

        echo $after;

        if ( sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
            echo $delimiter;
        }
    }

    echo $wrap_after;

}
```

**Tested and works.**

[image]

Comment: it works fine, Thanks @Bhautik

Comment: Actually you can just strip off the whole if/else statement and keep the `echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) ...`

Comment: But it will not work when `index` is 0